# Missing Type UIEvent?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm using XCode 10.2 with SpriteKit and swift 5 to create a Mac Application, and I cannot for the life of me find a working example of handling click events on a node.

The most updated info I can find suggests using the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { }
```

But XCode **errors**, saying

```
Use of undeclared type 'UIEvent'
Use of undeclared type 'UITouch'
```

I'm not sure how to proceed cause all the info I find suggests using the above code.  Everything else is working OK so far though.  Here is my GameScene Class:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var circle: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode();
    var label: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode();
    var ground: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode();

    /**
     * Did Move Callback
     */
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        initGround(view: view);
        initLabel(view: view);

        let recognizer = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap));
        view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
    }

    /**
     * Click Handler
     */
    @objc func tap(recognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) {
        let viewLocation = recognizer.location(in: view);
        let sceneLocation = convertPoint(fromView: viewLocation);

        addCircle(view: view!, position: sceneLocation);
    }

    // Not Working
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    }

    /**
     * Init Ground
     */
    func initGround(view: SKView) {

        let path = CGMutablePath();
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 30));
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width, y: 30));
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.width, y: view.frame.height));
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.height));
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 30));

        ground.path = path;
        ground.lineWidth = 5;
        ground.strokeColor = SKColor.brown;

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: path);
        borderBody.friction = 5;
        self.physicsBody = borderBody;

        addChild(ground);
    }

    /**
     * Add Label
     */
    func initLabel(view: SKView) {

        label = SKLabelNode(text: "No Gravity");
        label.name = "no gravity button";
        label.position = CGPoint(x: label.frame.width / 2, y: 5);
        label.fontSize = 12;
        label.fontColor = SKColor.yellow;
        label.fontName = "Avenir";
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;

        addChild(label);
    }

    /**
     * Add Circle
     */
    func addCircle(view: SKView, position: CGPoint) {
        let size = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 50);
        let color = getRandomColor();

        circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size));

        // Set Position
        circle.position = position;

        // Set Physics
        circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size));
        circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
        circle.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true;
        circle.physicsBody?.restitution = 1; //0.8
        circle.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0;
        circle.physicsBody?.friction = 0; //0.2
        circle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true;
        circle.physicsBody?.mass = CGFloat(size);
        circle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true;
        circle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -1000);

        circle.strokeColor = color;
        circle.glowWidth = 1.0;
        circle.fillColor = color;

        addChild(circle)
    }

    func getRandomColor() -> SKColor {
        return SKColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                       green: .random(in: 0...1),
                       blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Does anyone have experience with using Swift 5 and handling clicks / touches in SpriteKit?  Or maybe just why XCode says that UIEvent and UITouch aren't real things?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for an iOS or a Mac application? – UIEvent is from UIKit (iOS), and NSGestureRecognizer is from AppKit (macOS)

Comment: Edited question, it's a Mac Application - but I assumed it should work on either, no?

Comment: UIEvent, UITouch, ...  are from UIKit, that is iOS only.

Comment: Well, shoot - I guess that makes sense then.  I'm still no closer to finding the documentation or examples for detecting clicked node though :/  That is super helpful to know though

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you’ll implement

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
}

- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
}
```

In each case you will call

```
CGPoint loc = [theEvent locationInNode:self];
```

to learn where the click happened within the scene.

Comment: Google is your friend. https://www.raywenderlich.com/2299-how-to-port-your-sprite-kit-game-from-ios-to-os-x

Comment: The problem is that it's from 2015, most of that code isn't valid anymore with swift v5

Answer (score 0):

User [Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1187415/martin-r) pointed out the UIEvent and UITouch classes are included only in iOS projects.  I'm creating a Mac Application, what I didn't realize was that I already had the click handler in my GameScene class:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let recognizer = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(click));
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
}
```

This registers a callback to a click handler, which I already had defined:

```
/**
 * Click Handler
 */
@objc func tap(recognizer: NSGestureRecognizer) {
    let viewLocation = recognizer.location(in: view);
    let sceneLocation = convertPoint(fromView: viewLocation);
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(sceneLocation);

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "no gravity button" {
            print("Touched")
        }
    }

    addCircle(view: view!, position: sceneLocation);
}
```

I was able to get the clicked node name and act upon it as I originally intended.